# Error in executing xpath expression in c#

Tags: c#, xpath

I have the following code to execute xpath expression:

```
nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("if(count(//Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='SUBCLAIM']) > 1)
then //Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='SUBCLAIM']   else //Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='CLAIM']");
```

But it is giving me xpath exception like:

> if(count(//Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='SUBCLAIM']) > 1) then   //Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='SUBCLAIM']   else //Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='CLAIM']" has invalid token

Comment: You should probably show your XML

Comment: Always post example XML, you will receive better answers when doing so. Also read about the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Your current query is saying "If there are at least two subclaims in all input, return those, otherwise return all claims". Is this what you want to achieve? As far as I can derive your XML structure from your expression, I'm not too sure about that. And: You should accept answers if they solved your question, read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1.0 there is no if/then/else, but you can fake it using opposing predicates and node set union:

```
//Claims[count(//Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='SUBCLAIM'])>1][ClaimNoticeCd='SUBCLAIM']
  |
//Claims[count(//Claims[ClaimNoticeCd='SUBCLAIM'])<=1][ClaimNoticeCd='CLAIM']
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement you're using is XPath 2.0. The .NET framework doesn't support XPath 2.0 and you'll have to rely on 3rd party libraries if you require it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx